# Show the existence of a particular map from the compactification of a space to its one-point compactification.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

I'm trying to do the following exercise.

[image]

I've been looking around but have not seen the definition of the map *i*. Is it just an open embedding or is it something else? What are its properties?

Also, I plan to proceed with the proof by assuming that *f* exists and then finding its definition. If $k \in K$ is such that $k = e(x)$ for some $x \in X$, and if *i* is indeed an open embedding, then can I just simply state $f(k)$ to be such that $i(x) = f \circ e(x) = f(k)$ holds? What about the other case where $k \notin e(X)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume (you should really check exercise sheet 4 for this) that $i(x)=x$ and $X^+ = X \cup \{\infty\}$ for some point $\infty \notin X$, topologised in the usual way (all open sets of $X$ are also open in $X^+$ and we add all subsets of $X^+$ that contain $\infty$ and whose complement is a compact subset of $X$) and this implies in particular that $i(x)=x$ from $X$ to $X^+$ is an open embedding.

It's clear that you have no choice in defining $f$ on $e[X]$: $f(y)=x$ when $y=e(x) \in e[X]$ and then define $f(y)=\infty$ otherwise (i.e. $y \in K\setminus e[X]$). Check that this is continuous, which is easy with the topology on $X^+$ as described above. Also, $e[X]$ is dense in $K$ so once we've defined $f$ on that, it is uniquely determined (as $X^+$ is Hausdorff), by a standard theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$1).\ e(X)$ is open in $K$.

$2).\ $ Let $\infty$ be the point added to $X$ to obtain $X^+$ and define $f:K\to X^+$ by

$ f(k)=\begin{cases} 
      e^{-1}(k) & k\in e(X)\\
      \infty & k\in K\setminus e(X) \\ 
   \end{cases}$

$3).\ $ show $f$ is continuous, using $1).$

edit:

$1).$ is the hardest step, and follows from the fact that if $A\subseteq X$ is locally compact and $X$ is Hausdorff, then $A$ is open in $\overline A$.

Indeed, let $a\in A$ and $N_a$ be a neighborhood of $a$ (in $A$), such that cl$_A N_a:=K$ is compact. Then, there is an open set $V$ in $X$ such that $A\cap V=N_a.$

The foregoing implies that  $\overline{A\cap V}\cap A=\overline N_a\cap A=$cl$_A N_a=K$ so $\overline{A\cap V}\cap A$ is compact and therefore closed in $X$.

But $A\cap V\subseteq \overline{A\cap V}\cap A$ and we just showed that the RHS of this is closed, so $\overline {A\cap V}\subseteq \overline{A\cap V}\cap A$ and so $\overline {A\cap V}\subseteq\overline N_a\cap A\subseteq A$.

And since $V\cap\overline A\subseteq \overline {V\cap A}$, (because $V$ is open in $X$), it follows that $V\cap\overline A$ is contained in $A$, contains $a$, and is open in $\overline A$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: $X$ is not a subset of $K$..

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed my answer. Anyway, I think one can assume wlog that $X\subseteq K$ and $X\subseteq X^+$ because the usual ordering $\ge$ on compactifications is well behaved on the equivalence classes of compactifications of $X$.

Comment: 1) deserves a proof.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, it was harder than I thought. (I admit I hadn't remembered the proof). I have edited my answer.